# Angular 4 Singleton Services

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a service to share the data between two components. I injected the service into root module to make it accessible throughout the application by doing DI into the root module provider. My code looks roughly like this.

**Service**

```
    @Injectable(){
    export class ForumService{
       forum: any;

       setForum(object){
          this.forum = object; 
       }

       getForum(){
          return this.forum;
       }
    }
```

**Root Module**

```
.......
import { ForumService } from 'forumservice';
.......

@NgModule({
  declarations: [.....],
  imports: [.....],
  providers: [....., ForumService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

**Component One**

```
//A bunch of import statements

import { ForumService } from 'forumservice'; //Without this Angular throws a compilation error

@Component({
  selector: 'app-general-discussion',
  templateUrl: './general-discussion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./general-discussion.component.css'],
  providers: [GeneralDiscussionService]     //Not injecting ForumService again
})

export class GeneralDiscussionComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private forumService: ForumService){}

  ngOnInit(){
     helperFunction();
  }

  helperFunction(){
     //Get data from backend and set it to the ForumService
     this.forumService.forum = data;
     console.log(this.forumService.forum); //prints the data, not undefined
  }
}
```

**Component Two**

```
//A bunch of import statements

import { ForumService } from 'forumservice'; //Without this Angular throws a compilation error

@Component({
   selector: 'app-forum',
   templateUrl: './forum.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./forum.component.css'],
   providers: []
})

export class ForumComponent implements OnInit {
   forumData: any;

   constructor(private forumService: ForumService){}

   ngOnInit(){
      this.forumData = this.forumService.forum;  // returns undefined         
   }
}
```

Once I navigate from Component One to Component Two I'm expecting "This is a string". However I get `undefined`. Is it because of the import statements in the component? If I remove that I see a compilation error saying that `ForumService` is not found.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a timing issue where the value is read before it is set. Try setting in the constructor instead of `ngOnInit`. My suggestion is to use a `BehaviorSubject` to solve this kind of problem instead of a just field.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getter and setter, use the object (not primitibe such as string) directly In your components.

**Your service**

```
@Injectable(){
export class ForumService{
   forum:any = {name:string};
}
```

**Component one**

```
export class GeneralDiscussionComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private forumService: ForumService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.forumService.forum.name="This is a string";
  }
}
```

**Component two**

```
export class ForumComponent implements OnInit {
// forumTitle: string; // do not need this anymore
   forum:any; // use the forum.name property in your html

   constructor(private forumService: ForumService){}

   ngOnInit(){
      this.forum = this.forumService.forum;  // use the          
   }
}
```

I know encapsulating is preferable, and with your current code you are probably encountering some timing problems. But when working with shared data in a service you can two-way bind the variable like above, and your components will be in sync.

**EDIT:**

Also an important notice, the variable you want to sync between components needs to be an object. instead of `forumTitle:string`, make it `forumTitle:any = {subject:string}` or something similar.

Otherwise you need to make your components as listeners for data when data changes in your service.

Comment: Still getting `undefined`. Is it because of the importing ForumService in components?

Comment: I just notice another important thing. The variable cannot be a primitive (such as string) it needs to be an object. E.g. `forumTitle:any = {subject:string};`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use BehaviorSubject in this case, should be something like that:

```
@Injectable(){
export class ForumService{
   private _forum: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
   public forum: Observable<any> = this._forum.asObservable();

   setForum(object){
      this._forum.next(object); 
   }

}
```

Then just bind it in template with async pipe: `{{forumService.forum|async}}` or subscribe to it.